# Android : Stop timer when a viewpager's page is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, timer, android-viewpager

Hi after multiple researches, i don't how to fix my problem. I tried lot of things and nothing work in my context. There is a solution or should I think for another way to do my task (simply that I never thought).

Context : I have a MainActivity with a viewpager for a best managment of fragments. The first fragment of the viewpager contains another viewpager which instantiate a new fragment for each object from an ArrayList.
The fragment with the viewpager have a timer (with two methods start/stop timer)for autoscrolling the pages of viewpager every 3/4 sec.

What I want to do : I want to stop the timer when the user click anywhere on the page of the viewpager and the timer restart when the user scrolls for the next page.

My problem : I tried to get the selected page and add a onclicklistener on the view of the fragment, but the selected page (fragment object) returns null. I tried to call the stopTimer() method from the fragment in the viewpager in OnCreateView (get the parent fragment and call the method) but the parent fragment returns null too. Everything I tried I got a NullPointerException.

I did a schema on Paint to try to explain you the context.

[Context schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEGgM.png)

```
public class FeedViewerFragment extends Fragment {
private static final int SWITCH_PERIOD = 3000;
Timer timer;
int page = 0;
private FeedViewPager mViewPager;
private FeedPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
private ArrayList<User> users;
private TimerTask timerTask;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private boolean timerIsRunning;
private FeedViewerFragment thisInstance;

public static final FeedViewerFragment newInstance(ArrayList<User> users) {
    FeedViewerFragment f = new FeedViewerFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("feed_users", users);
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.users = (ArrayList<User>) getArguments().getSerializable("feed_users");
    this.thisInstance = this;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed_viewer, container, false);

    mViewPagerAdapter = new FeedPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), users);
    mViewPager = (FeedViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_view_feed_viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setAllowedSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection.right);
    startTimer();
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (!timerIsRunning)
                startTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


    return view;
}

private void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();

    initializeTimerTask();

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1500, SWITCH_PERIOD); //
}

public void stopTimer() {
    timer.cancel();
    timerIsRunning = false;
}

private void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            timerIsRunning = true;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (page > mViewPagerAdapter.getCount()) {
                        page = 0;
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
                    } else {
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page++);
                    }
                }
                });
            }
        };
    }

private class FeedPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<User> users;

    public FeedPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(fm);
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FeedProfileFragment.newInstance(this.users.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

}

}
```

Above, it's the first fragment from the MainActivity's viewpager which contains the timer to autoscroll his viewpager. I want to call the stopTimer() method when the user clicked on the current page of the viewpager.

Sorry for my english, I tried to write the most correct I can.
Thank's for the time you'll take to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setOnClickListener on the Fragment's root layout! I think Hanlder.postdelay is better than Timer

Comment: Which fragment's root layout : the one with the viewpager or the one contained by the viewpager ? I will see for the handler, for the moment the Timer works fine.

Comment: I tried on the root view of the fragment which contains the viewpager and it doesnt work. The click wont be fired.